# Is there an iOS equivalent of Fluid for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, ios

I'd like to run a [Freeboard.io dashboard](https://freeboard.io/) (HTML+JavaScript) on an older iPad to visualize a bunch of things persistently. This would be fine as a Safari home-screen-ified app, except [there's no way to prevent display sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709891/prevent-ios-mobile-safari-from-going-idle-auto-locking-sleeping) without globally changing the iPad's lock settings.

It's easy enough to [programmatically disable sleep in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661004/how-to-disable-enable-the-sleep-mode-programmatically-in-ios), but I don't want to pay $99/year for an Apple developer account just so I can make a UIWebView in an app that disables the sleep timer.

And yes, [Panic's Status Board](http://panic.com/statusboard/) exists—but apparently it's buggy and not being actively developed anymore. It's more sensible than a $99/year subscription, but still not ideal.

What I'd love is the equivalent of [Fluid.app](http://fluidapp.com/) for Mac, just for iOS and obviously with the option to disable the sleep timer.

**Does a suitable iOS app exist, or would Apple reject any candidate because it'd be nothing more than a UIWebView wrapper?**

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19753318/3874884). Google basically reloads the page, and then stops it reloading.

```
iosSleepPreventInterval = setInterval(function () {
window.location.href = "/new/page";
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.stop()
}, 0);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Referenced programmatic sleep disabling in my post. I only intend to use this privately, which is helping to make the situation surprisingly difficult!

Comment: I found a solution, I skipped over the part where you don't want an app, sorry!

Comment: No worries, though I want to use an app if it exists. I just don't have a ADC account so it's excessive to subscribe so I can get a 10-minute app on my iPad. (Or jailbreak or whatever.) I tested this JavaScript and it didn't work alongside the freeboard.io dashboard unfortunately--I linked to a related SE post in my question.

Comment: Could it be possible you create a separate page, and add the dashboard in a iframe or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to your question. Now this answer doesn't actually assist you in resolving your issues, however it's more accurately an answer than a comment so I acted accordingly.

First, an app can only directly effect the device with Public API processes while its active, or with *special* permission, while its in the background. The idle timer in this case, is an active state reference, so there would be no way a developer could alter this in the background (while using Public API and fulfilling App Store requirements). So no, no app can directly alter that setting in the App Store for any tasks outside of its bundle. This is probably a security issue to Apple that's why they don't allow it. For example you could set my idle timer off without even asking my permission but turn my screen black to emulate a locked device and use that for whatever reason you see fit (take pictures videos etc)

Secondly,
There are App Store guidelines but they seem to vary based on Apples mood for the day. Some apps get rejected for being a 'Website wrapper' while others don't. It's unfortunate but been a living breathing dragon in the App Store ecosystem. So it's hard to say they will reject it because no one really knows until you submit it. Is it worth it in your case? No. Because your alternatives are cheaper. 
1) Jailbreak your phone. 2) ask a developer to just ad hoc an app to you. Based off your description you just want a web view and the timer set off, doesn't seem like a troubled development